# Selenium - Cross domain and HTTPS problem

Tags: https, selenium, cross-domain, selenium-rc

I use Selenium to test my website. The website need to access an external catalog to select some items from it. The problem is this catalog is published on another domain with HTTPS protocol. I've searched and read many topics on the internet about Selenium and Cross domain problems, but I still don't find the answer yet. Some topics said that the *iehta browser will overcome this issue, but in fact it could not do that. I also try *iexplore, *iexploreproxy, *firefox, *firefoxproxy as well, but the results are the same. Could you please give me the solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried it, but the result is the same as ones I had tried before.

Answer (score 2):

The *iexplore (HTA mode) and *firefox (chrome mode) launchers will work just fine.  *googlechrome will work in the forthcoming 2.0 release.  As for the mechanics of making SSL work, the following article may help:

http://mogotest.com/blog/2010/04/13/how-to-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificates-in-selenium

Answer (score 2):

I've used the -trustAllSSLCertificates option with success.

Go to the site first with a normal IE connection, you get the message:

**There is a problem with this website's security certificate.**

Then:

**Click Continue to this website (not recommended).**

You'll see there's a red "Certificate Error" box at the top of the browser.

Click that, click "View Cetificates" then "Add" and add the certificate to the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities". There are similar screenshots for this process in the "mogotest" link in the previous answer.

Now run Selenium with the -trustAllSSLCertificates option and you are away.

Comment: I did the same but now after executing test scripts. \server seems to be hanging, \it opens the url fine but then just stays there. ANy idea