# Certificate issue while writing script using selenium

Tags: c#-4.0, selenium

Imported a certificate for security purpose of our website. Doing manually the page loads properly but using script throwing an error ![enter image description here][1]

An error occur during connection to URL(required website)
SSL peers cannot verify your certificate.
Error Code (ssl_error_bad_cert_alert)

Thanks a lot for any kind of help.

Comment: Your image is not visible for us. :)

Comment: not able to attach the image. therefore mentioned the error i am getting

Comment: error message is mentioned above. What should i do. Tried changing the url https to http or www. Added the url as exception in FF browser

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a self-signed certificate?
Have a look at this question, basically they are suggesting to use a -trustAllSSLCertificates switch.

[Selenium Testing HTTPs Trust All certificates working for FF but not IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575817/selenium-testing-https-trust-all-certificates-working-for-ff-but-not-ie) switch